# Iterating through dataframe with pandas and replacing characters

Tags: python, pandas

My data frame column named 'Shrinkage' looks like:

```
-Shrinkage
-($614)
-$0
-$0
-$0
-$0
-$0
-$0
-$0
-($125)
-$320
-$3,779
($2,482)
```

With the following code, I am trying to perform multiple actions with a for loop and if statement. I would like to iterate through the column and if the object has the character '(' then I want to replace it with the character '-' to make that number negative. As well as finding and replacing the negative numbers, I would like to remove all characters and make the objects into floats to perform math with it.

```
for i in ['Shrinkage']:
    if df['Shrinkage'] == '(':
        df['Shrinkage'] = df['Shrinkage'].replace({'(': '-'}).astype(float)
        df['Shrinkage'] = df['Shrinkage'].replace({'$': '', ')': '', ',': ''})
    else:
        df['Shrinkage'].replace({'$': '', ',': ''}, regex=True).astype(float)
```

I am getting a ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Please understand I am still new to python and haven't got into complex code yet. Some help is needed please.

Comment: hey, when there's an error in python usually there's also traceback printed - which shows which exact line caused the error and what was the execution stack. Take a look and you will see which exact line is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks! @PrzemysławCzechowski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, [series.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) and use regex to remove un-wanted characters.

```
df['Shrinkage'] = df['Shrinkage'].str.replace("\(|\$|\)|,", "")

print(df['Shrinkage'].astype(float))
```

output,

```
0     -614.0
1       -0.0
2       -0.0
3       -0.0
4       -0.0
5       -0.0
6       -0.0
7       -0.0
8     -125.0
9     -320.0
10   -3779.0
11    2482.0
Name: Shrinkage, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
df['Shrinkage'] = df['Shrinkage'].str.replace('\$|\)|\,', '')
df['Shrinkage'] = df['Shrinkage'].str.replace('\(', '-')
df['Shrinkage'] = df['Shrinkage'].astype(float)
print(df)


    Shrinkage
0      -614.0
1         0.0
2         0.0
3         0.0
4         0.0
5         0.0
6         0.0
7         0.0
8      -125.0
9       320.0
10     3779.0
11    -2482.0
```